# Unable To Call three function together in my php script?

Tags: php, function

Hi I am printing data through a function but now i need some more data from other resource for which i need to call three more function how can i call all of them together.

Here is my code for calling one function, now how can i implement it like this so all three function call together -

```
    <?php

// get database connection
include_once '../database.php';
// instantiate user object
include_once 'service.php';
// header('Content-type: text/javascript');
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$user = new User($db);
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.xls"');

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

// set user property values
$user->clientid = $_POST['clientid'];
// create the user
if($user->getOthersKeywords() ){  //calling getOthersKeywords() function here i need to call three function here too how?
    $GetData=$user->GetData;      

}


else{
    $GetData=array(
        "Error" => "Error",
        "message" => "No Record Found"
    );
}
// print_r(json_encode($GetData));
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Remove the code that is not relevant to your questions and point where exactly is that problematic call?

Comment: Where are the 3 functions that you need to call. When do you need to call them.

Comment: i edited the code please check like this if($user->getOthersKeywords() ){
    $GetData=$user->GetData; 

} i need to call getcompanydata(), getkeydata() functions too

Comment: i edite my code please check once@MilanG

Comment: Not really sure what the problem/question is, but you can just call other functions after `$GetData=$user->GetData;`. Other than that please explain what "_i need to call three more like this here_" means

Comment: @kerbholz sir i call a function if($user->getOthersKeywords() and now i want to call three more function exactly here but don'tknow how

Comment: Like `if($user->getOthersKeywords() && $user->getcompanydata() && $user->getkeydata()) {...`?